# R: big.matrix multiplication

Tags: r, matrix, r-bigmemory

All,

I am working with R2.14 on 64-bit Windows 7.

I am trying to square a big.matrix object (big thanks to the developers), and may require raising it to a higher power.

From my research the bigalgebra package would be right up my street, but it seems to be still under construction.

Is there any alternative for algebra on a big.matrix object?

Thanks in advance.
W.

Comment: If you're doing a higher power, and the matrix is diagonalizable, you probably want to use the Diagonal matrix identity A=PDP'; A^n=PD^nP';, since a diagonal matrix to a power is just its individual elements to the power, which is MUCH faster to calculate.

Comment: Is the number of elements in the matrix large or the values of the matrix element large? If you want to multiply a matrix with large number of elements and you don't find help from package, you can do it by partitioning the matrix and carrying out the multiplication and adding them later.

Answer (score 3):

Just try this for **bigalgebra**:

```
install.packages("bigalgebra", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

This have to work!